# best high pass filter topology to extract low V kHz range pulse from noisy 60Hz line voltage before daq

Tags: voltage-measurement, pulse, high-pass-filter

I need to extract a 1 kHz-10kHz range voltage pulse created by a current pulse I inject on an harmonic rich 60 Hz network and that propagates on it.
The line voltage is 120V AC. harmonics 2 and 3 are significant
The amplitude of the pulsed voltage signal I need to measure is a few V at most. I need the best possible accuracy on the measured pulse voltage.
I am not sure of the best strategy to perform these measurements and seek advice on this.

As of now I plan to use a 24 bit +/- 10v 1MS/s acquisition module. In order not to loose the information contained in the pulse,  my current idea is to design an analog filter with fast transient response so that I don't distort the pulse and  that will remove enough of the line voltage to bring the total signal under 10V peak while amplifying the part above say 500 Hz by a few db so that I can use the full daq capabilities and then use digital processing.
I can calibrate the filter if necessary.

I am not a filter experts and I don't know how to select the best filter topology to achieve these goals.
Any ideas or suggestions will be needed.
Thank you
Regarding safety  and because I cannot use insulating transformer I will use very small fuse.

Comment: See if you can get a clean 60hz from somewhere and subtract it from your signal. For instance, you could filter out the higher frequency and the resulting 60hz waveform would be your reference.

Comment: You're saying you're injecting a *current* pulse. That implies on top of a distorted *current* waveform. Can you tell more about the mains current? What amplitude, how large the harmonics, but also about the pulse, because the specs are awfully vague (1...10 kHz range, a few mV?). Suppose the signal is 1 mV peak (or pp?), the bandwidth must be known. Also, two things: a recovery of the precise shape of the pulse might not be possible, and fast settling might not mean a few pulses, but tens or more (depending on the bandwidth/center frequency).

Comment: "Best possible" is not a design spec. Why are you doing this?

Comment: No fuse will help you btw. The fuse blows *after the damage is done !*

Comment: Strongly agree with the suggestion to record the base AC waveform on a second channel.  This is a situation where a differential measurement will give you dramatically more robust results.

Answer (score 2):

I'd definitely not bother too much on analog filtering.
24 bits is such resolution that you get some 20 uV resolution even on the plain full input spectrum.

Mains network own noise is far above that even in the 1 kHz- 10 kHz band of interest due the heap of switch mode power supplies and lamp drivers connected.

[image]
(Reserch gate https://www.researchgate.net/publication/289721425)

This sample shows noise in the range of millivolt in that band.
So all in all I'd rather go for a simple first order highpass tuned on 100 Hz (approx -6dB on the 60 Hz fundamental, i.e. approx 10 uV resolution).

Then you'll have to struggle on the digital processing, here you can deploy a pretty brickwall shaped filter and /or some FFT and/or some syncronous demodulation scheme trying to recover the informations you are after.

And do not forget an anti-aliasing low pas filter, as you can see there's plenty of rubbish on the highside of spectrum too.

Comment: Thanks for your input a high pass filter is indeed necessary to bring down the 60 Hz voltage level in the dac range. I want to take advantage of it to amplify the 1 kHz-10 kHz signal as I measured then oise on the network and it is sub mV. so that I can take full advantage of the dac resolution

Comment: The antialiasing lowpass filter is somenthing I did not think of. Thanks a lotfor pointing it out! In insight its absolutely necessary indeed.